# Searching for real solutions of $2^x = \frac{3}{4}x + \frac{5}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

I'm looking for real solutions to the following equation:
$$2^x = \frac{3}{4}x + \frac{5}{4}$$
By plotting the functions I've found that the solutions should be $\pm 1$, however I this approach is not viable for solving similar problems in the future.

I'm curious, how would one approach an equation such as this algebraically, since I have no prior experience with equations of similar structure.

Comment: In general you can use numerical methods or the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: 1) Find solutions ad hoc. 2) Use calculus to show the ad hoc solutions are the only ones.

Comment: The two sides of the equation are an exponential and a line.  Since the exponential does not change its curvature, the line can meet it in at most two real locations.  Various numeric methods may be useful, like Newton-Raphson (sp?) etc., but finding solutions using simple methods like graphing can be just as useful as numeric methods in terms of helping to see what is happening.

Comment: I did not try to solve it, but I am so sure that numerical approach regarding roots finding will find solutions...

Comment: $2^{x+2}=3x+5,\,2^{x+2}=3(x+2)-1$, since $(2^{x+2})''=2^{x+2}\ln^2 2>0$ it can intersect an arbitrary straight line not more than twice.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=2^x$ is a convex function, which says that the line $y=\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{5}{4}$ and a graph of $f$ have two common points maximum.

But by your work $1$ and $-1$ are roots of the equation, which says that our equation  has no another roots.

This way does not help in the general, if you want to get roots in elementary functions.